# Unable to fetch data from Mongodb using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, twitter-oauth

Im new to node js. Playing with different things. Presently im able to fetch data from twitter and also able to store it in mongodb database. Now i want to fetch the stored database from mongodb and display it on browser. Can any one please help me out in fetching and displaying data .....

```html
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer(),
    twitter = require('ntwitter');
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('tweakdb', ['tweakdb']);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


var a='love';
var b='hate';

var watchList = [a, b];
var twit = new twitter({
  consumer_key: '',
consumer_secret: '',
access_token_key: '',
access_token_secret: ''
});

twit.stream('statuses/filter', { track: watchList }, function(stream) {
  stream.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log(data.user.screen_name + ': ' + data.text);
    console.log(data);
    console.log("\n\n\n\n");
    db.tweakdb.findAndModify({
        query: {'id': 'data.id'},
        update: { $set: data},
        upsert: true,
        new: true
    })
});
});



app.listen(3000);
```

Above i have pasted running code of app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to get tweets from mongo document in router

```
router.get('/tweets', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    //you can filter tweets by screen name or other fields
    // var query = {"user.screen_name":"PUT_HERE_AS_PER_YOUR_REQUIREMENT"};
        db.tweakdb.find().toArray(function(err, tweets) {
            if(err) {
                res.status(err.status || 500);
                res.render('error', {
                    message: err.message,
                    error: err
                });
            } else {
                res.json(tweets);
                //res will get into router
            }

        });
});
```

now rendering tweets.jade as per express template routing

> //tweets.jade

```
extends layout

    block content
        h1.
            Tweet List
        ul
            each tweet, i in tweets
                li
                    tweet.id = tweet.text = tweet.place
```

You need to understand jade template structure via [link](http://jade-lang.com/)

Comment: I am getting the following error :     router.get('/tweets', function(req, res) {
^
ReferenceError: router is not defined.

Comment: Im very much thankful for your support till now. But im not able to resolve this issue, can you please help us to resolve this so that we can move forward and learn more about node and express js. Please help us to display the tweets on web page.

Comment: Thanks for you kind words but its truth that i m not here for teaching line by line. You should start own by learning from zero. It will make a big difference to understand about express otherwise you will never understand the code what you expect from here

Comment: Again i need to thank you... I was able to resolve things after a try... Thank you. I was able to display tweets on webpage... Now trying to sort the tweets based on some criteria. Have a nice time...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [MongoClient](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html) to connect with your database.

An example will be:

```
 var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient // Driver for connecting to MongoDB
var app = express.createServer();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/tweakdb', function(err, db) {
        db.collection("tweakdb").find({query}, {fields}, function(err, items) {
            if(err) throw err;
            res.render(items);
        })
    }
});

// spin up server
app.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1')
```

And when you finish your work with mongodb call "db.close()" to close connection.

I recommend you nodeJS+mongodb course from [university.mongodb.com](http://university.mongodb.com)